# QGIS rounds up the coordinates to six decimals when saving layer changes

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have the problem that when I create a new point (in a point layer) or a new line (in a line layer of course) and I save the changes to the layer (so NOT the project save) then QGIS rounds up the coordinates of the new element to six decimals. I can see that in the "identify results" window by clicking on "(Derived"). So as a result, I don't get the required position of the new element. The layers are DB tables that I received and I just open them in QGIS. I don't know the source of the layers. The CRS of the project is the same as the CRS of the layer. The thing is, if I create a new shapefile-layer myself (point for example), the new element remains in the wanted location even after saving layer changes. So it has something to do with the layer I received. But I don't know what that is. I am trying for 3 days to find a solution and can't seem to solve the problem. Does anyone have a hint for me?

Bevore saving the layer changes:
[image: bevore save]

After saving the layer changes:
[image: after save]

Comment: What is the format of the layer that you have?  Shape?

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know. I access the layer from a network database (MSSQL/dbo) and can't see any extension of the file. I suspect it is not a shapefile. Heard these is data translated somehow in osm format. Unfortunately i can not find out more today about the source of the layer. Any idea?

Comment: Well I guess it's just a database layer.

Comment: @Nathan W that sounds plausible. But still, why does QGIS round up?

Comment: I don't think QGIS would be rounding up.  Do you see a shift in the placement of the points. Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: Yes, i see a shift. Screenshot coming right up.

Comment: If the geometries are stored in a database, database settings might limit the number of digits.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in QGIS. I've created a bug report [here](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/7638).

It relates to the MS SQL data provider using WKT by default to save and update records. The `QgsGeometry::exportToWkt()` method rounds coordinates to 6 decimal places. In more recent versions, this has been increased to 8, but it is still rounding.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an issue with floating point calculation where in binary computers can't see recurring numbers and therefore can't round.  It doesn't matter if you're in a billion dollar ArcGIS development environment or QGIS world, the issue is that you are in binary base2.